# Counter Example to Darboux's theorem.

Tags: analysis

I am looking for a function that does not satisfy [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) (the Intermediate Value Theorem).

Maybe it will not be continuous [a,b] or not differentiable on (a,b).

Comment: If it is a theorem, there should not be a counterexample.  It is a good question to eliminate one assumption of the theorem and try to find a counterexample.  Often that improves your understanding of the theorem.  Which assumption would you like to remove?

Comment: doesn't matter any assumption

Comment: You are looking for a piece of hay in a haystack. Hardly any functions satisfy Darboux. Try, e.g., the fractional part function. Or, the floor function.

Answer (score 3):

Try $f(x)=|x|$ on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Well, this function doesn't differentiable on (-1,1) but it is satisfy the rest of Darboux's theorem. I mean it satisfy that if c,d are in [-1,1] and k is between f'(c) and f'(d) then there is t between c and d such that f(t)=k.

Comment: In other words I want to see a function f(x) that is if c and d are in domain of f(x) and k is between of f(c) and f(d), then there is t not between c and d such that f(t)=k

Comment: Okay, try $f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x\le 0 \\ 1 & x>0\end{cases}$ on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Comment: for this function, is there c and d in [-1,1] and k between f(c) and f(d) but there is t not between c and d and f(t)=k??